# Document rendering in android

Tags: android, rendering, text-rendering, rendering-engine, font-rendering

How the document viewer displays and renders document.

Does converting document to bitmap (by taking glyph and painting) and painted on canvas is the best way or there is any other way.

Comment: What do you mean the "document viewer"? PDFs?

Comment: @Nicolas applications like odf,odt, docx viewer etc